# Run SQL at a certain date/time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, model-view-controller

I've got a Microsoft SQL database containing a table called Bookings with a column EndDate and a column Status.

Whenever a row is inserted into Bookings, it will set the Status to be unavailable and insert an EndDate (like a week from now).

What I want to do is to automatically update Status from unavailable to available when the current date and time is equal to EndDate.

I can't use SQL Server Agent Jobs since I'm running Express Edition.

Thanks

Comment: If I proper unserstood you then try to use trigger FOR INSERT

Comment: @MegaTron has mentioned correctly. Trigger for Insert it is!!! EUREKA!!! EUREKA!!!

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a computed column. Just add the logic in the column and there is no need to do anything else. The next best choice would be a view like Tom H posted below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a dangerous path that you want to go down. As soon as this process gets missed once you now have rows out there that have invalid data. Not to mention, you're spending an awful lot of processing time (and maintenance) just to mark a column that you should be able to determine at any point in time anyway.

Instead of trying to maintain duplicate data in your database (which will invariably get out of sync), just calculate it at run time or create a view to present it:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Bookings_WithStatus
AS
    SELECT
        booking_id,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(end_date, GETDATE()) > GETDATE() THEN 'Unavailable'
            ELSE 'Available'
        END AS booking_status
    FROM
        dbo.Bookings
```

Although the logic is simple enough that I probably wouldn't even bother with a view myself.

@Sean Lange makes the excellent point that this can also be done as a computed column, which is probably better than using a view:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Bookings
DROP COLUMN booking_status

ALTER TABLE dbo.Bookings
ADD booking_status AS
    CASE
        WHEN COALESCE(end_date, GETDATE()) > GETDATE() THEN 'Unavailable'
        ELSE 'Available'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this logic constantly and if you can't use SQL Agent, maybe you need to consider a simple application like Windows Service or Console Application.
This can be triggered once per day by Windows Scheduler and that will go through all the records in your database, check if your conditions have met and update records if it is necessary?

Comment: @SimonKarlsson Quartz is certainly an option, but requires an external application to be installed - a console application run by the Windows task scheduler doesn't require anything external to be installed. It's a good option if you find it easier to work with.

Comment: @Jake However if you use quartz you will have a self-contained application, which imo is more clean than running something in the task scheduler. As of today there is nothing wrong with using a 3rd party library, a lot of people makes the mistake nowadays by reinventing the wheel instead of using an existing library.

Comment: In its simplest form, the console application would connect to SQL and run a stored procedure, and that part of the code would remain the same even with Quartz. To solve the issue of getting it to run at a certain time, you could either A. open an existing application on your computer, set up the time(s), and point it to the script, or B. install a new application and learn how to use it to achieve the same result. I use Quartz for more complex things, but if you have a single console application to run at a regular interval, it's not exactly "reinventing the wheel"

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by a service or a script run using sqlcmd, but I'd be inclined to step back and look at the base requirement.

To what end must the Status change at that exact time? The output data that you're looking for sounds much like it could be better accomplished using a view rather than a persisted field, and with much less complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without updating the status column might be sufficient. Your "available" rows are those whose EndDate is greater or equal to GETUTCDATE() assuming EndDate is in UTC